# Current Election Voting Results Summary

Tags: discussion, election

I tried searching meta if this has already been covered in the past but couldn't find it.

Is there a way I can see the current status of the voting results in a table? Something like this at a click of a button?

[image]

I can write a macro for this and it will take me 15 mins for that but wanted to be sure that I am not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User [Jeremy Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) has created script that can be used in the JavaScript Console of your browser it is located on [github](https://gist.github.com/jeremybanks/2913432/raw/0a153bd0b93bbd440298ea011792ec521e2114f7/soElectionGraphs.js).  He posted this in the [Election Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47184/2014-stack-overflow-moderator-election)- here is the [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14764645#14764645)

> @MadaraUchiha Copy this script into your JavaScript console on the election page: gist.github.com/jeremybanks/2913432/raw/…
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. I am kind of novice and am sure many of us might be when it comes to using the JavaScript Console of the browser. Can you shed more light on it? I mean what is it and how do I use it? Thanks for taking the time out to reply. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Depending on your browser, you should have a tools option with Javascript Console.  For example, I use Chrome if I go to Tools, there is a selection for the console.  You can paste the script into the window.

Comment: Thank you. Let me test it.

Comment: + 1 I couldn't figure it out so I wrote a small macro instead. i am sure the script that you mentioned works :)

Comment: For anyone interested, I've made a [small change](https://gist.github.com/stijnherreman/9069487) so it includes your own vote at the end.

Answer (score 9):

Edit History

Version 2 Updated at the end of the post.

---

Ok an alternative.

I created a **small** macro. You can download the file from [THIS](http://wikisend.com/download/334014/SO%20Election%20Votes%20status.xlsm) link

**Prerequisite**:

1. You should have MS Excel 2007+ with macros enabled.
2. Ensure you have IE and you are logged in with "Remember the password" option. After that you may close the browser.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Script/Code:**

People who are not able to visit that site can create a button in the worksheet and use this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument, htmlBod As HTMLBody
    Dim tr As HTMLTableRow, span As HTMLSpanElement
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim data() As String

    ReDim data(2, 500) As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/election"

    '~~> One may set it to false
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.Busy And IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set htmlDoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set htmlBod = htmlDoc.body

    htmlBod.innerHTML = IE.document.body.innerHTML
    htmlBod.innerHTML = htmlDoc.getElementById("mainbar").outerHTML

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    lastRow = 1

    For Each tr In htmlBod.getElementsByTagName("TR")
        If tr.ID Like "post-########" Then
            If tr.getElementsByClassName("user-details").Length > 1 Then
                data(1, lastRow) = tr.getElementsByClassName("user-details")(1).Children(0).innerText
                For Each span In tr.getElementsByTagName("span")
                    If span.className = "vote-count-post" Then
                        data(2, lastRow) = span.innerText
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve data(2, lastRow) As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Range("A:B").ClearContents

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = data(1, i)
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = data(2, i)
    Next

    ws.Columns("A:B").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub
```

Do set a reference to the respective libraries as shown in the pic below.

[image]

---

**EDIT - Version 2**

This will let you do a historic analysis between two candidates. Please select the names from the drop downs in the YELLOW Cell and click on `Compare`

Also you can only have 10 points of data in one table. After 10 points, you will have to clear the table by pressing `Clear` and then start all over again. To populate the table, click on `Refresh`

[image]

File can be downloaded from [HERE](http://wikisend.com/download/741638/SO%20Election%20Votes%20status%20ver%202.0.xlsm)